# Fix auto screen rotation on Fedora 33 (gnome)

Tags: fedora, gnome, troubleshooting, touch-screen

## Problem

Auto screen rotation used to work flawlessly. When I turned my laptop on its side (or upside down) the screen would turn as well (very handy for tablet mode).
Since the last update it doesn't work anymore. Also the little button in the top right corner menu (lock orientation) is gone.

## My System

- Lenovo X1 Yoga 4th (2in1 with touch)
- Fedora Workstation 33, Gnome 3.38.1
- uname: Linux x1-yoga 5.9.8-200.fc33.x86_64
- Software and firmware up to date.

## What I tried

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock false
```

(or true)
-> seems to have no effect. Screen doesn't rotate still.

```
sudo systemctl status iio-sensor-proxy.service
● iio-sensor-proxy.service - IIO Sensor Proxy service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iio-sensor-proxy.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-11-20 15:11:28 CET; 13min ago
   Main PID: 1069 (iio-sensor-prox)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18886)
     Memory: 1.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/iio-sensor-proxy.service
             └─1069 /usr/sbin/iio-sensor-proxy

Nov 20 15:11:28 x1-yoga systemd[1]: Starting IIO Sensor Proxy service...
Nov 20 15:11:28 x1-yoga systemd[1]: Started IIO Sensor Proxy service.
```

-> sensor seems to be up and running.

That's all I found online, so any help with this or instructions how to troubleshoot it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Lukas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found the solution. I'm documenting this here if anyone has the same problem.

Apparently with the update it changed the behavior of the screen rotation:

- no auto rotation when in clamshell mode available
- when in tent or tablet mode the autorotation button in the menu becomes available and can be toggled on/off. Rotation works then.

So my problem was not looking at the menu in tablet mode. I had autorotate off and just assumed it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. Seems like linux kernel regression (see https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=210269) along with mutter regression (see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1526).

As for kernel - not sure when it will land.
As for mutter - will land in 3.38.2 (https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/commit/9b9051c2172078e623e8a4b0e45e38004c394a92)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The problem that's described there isn't exactly the same as mine, but might be the same fix actually.

Comment: Hi! After updating to mutter 3.38.2-1.fc33 my problem (no autorotate + no onscreen keyboard) is gone.

Comment: I'm on the same mutter version but the problem still exists unfortunately.